# non linear matrix differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I found the following problem during my research (in cosmology):

given the functions $P_1(x),\ P_2(x),\ P_3(x)$, how to solve the system

\begin{equation}
\frac{d\ P_m}{dx} = P^t \cdot A_m \cdot P - P_m\ (P^t \cdot B \cdot P)\,, 
 \qquad \text{(1)}
\end{equation}

where $P^t= (P_1,P_2,P_3)$ is the transposed vector of $P$, $B(x)$ and $A_1(x),\ A_2(x),\ A_3(x)$ are arbitrary (but known) matrices, and a "$\cdot$" means product between the vectors and the matrices. Here $P_m$ is the $m$-component of the vector $P$.

PERTURBATIVE SOLUTION:
I can solve the system perturbatively. For instance, if I suppose that the matrices $A_m$ and $B$ are small. Then, given the initial condition $P_m(x=0)= q_m$, I can to first order set $P_m = q_m$ on the r.h.s of 
equation (1) to obtain:

\begin{equation}
P_m = q_m + q^t \cdot \left(\int dx\ A_m \right) \cdot q - q_m\ \left[q^t \cdot \left( \int dx\ B \right) \cdot q\right]\,, 
 \quad \text{(2)}
\end{equation}

and use this solution back into (1) to obtain a second order solution, and so on.

Is there a way to solve the system without going into perturbation theory?

Comment: What is $P_m$ ? What does $P_m\ (P^t \cdot B \cdot P)$ denote ?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. $P_m$ is the $m$-component of the vector $P$.

Comment: So this is a cubic ODE ? (In a scalar version, would be $P'=aP^2-bP^3$.)

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that.

Comment: Good and bad news: the scalar equation can be integrated, but not as an explicit function $P(x)$.

Comment: You are right: I found (in Mathematica) \begin{equation}
\int \frac{d P}{a P^2-b P^3}= - \frac{1}{a} \left[ \frac{ 1}{P} + \frac{ b}{a} \ln \left( \frac{ 1}{p} - \frac{ b}{a} \right) \right]
\end{equation}  But even an implicit solution would be nice for me.

Comment: If I am right, you can transform the system of ODE (presumably you are in 3D) in a single linear equation of the third order, by differentiating and eliminating two of the components. Anyway the coefficients will be polynomials, possibly of a higher degree, and the resolution risks to be a nightmare.

Comment: Hi @YvesDaoust, please take a look at pp.15 of my article https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08428 There I thank you for the help.